# Grails plugin resources not found when running using run-app

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-plugin

I have been using Spring Security core plugin without the UI for a while. Now I have to implement the interface for that so I naturally turned to the Spring Security UI plugin for Grails.

After running my project using grails run-app, I can hit the default controllers of the plugin, however it doesn't seem to find the resources that come with the spring-security UI. I checked *.grails\2.0.4\projects\Proteus\plugins\spring-security-ui-1.0-RC1* and everything seems to be there.

Packing and deploying the .WAR file through tomcat works fine. However, *run-war* has the same problem.

Does anyone have an idea on what might be causing this? Developing with this issue is quite painful.

Thank you!

I am using Grails 2.0.4

*Application.resources*

```
app.grails.version=2.0.4
app.name=Proteus
app.servlet.version=2.5
app.version=0.1
plugins.csv=0.3.1
plugins.famfamfam=1.0.1
plugins.mail=1.0.1
plugins.spring-security-core=2.0-RC2
plugins.spring-security-ui=1.0-RC1
```

Firebug console output when I hit `http://localhost:8080/Proteus/user/`

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:8080/Proteus/static/plugins/spring-security-ui-1.0-RC1/css/gradient.png"
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:8080/Proteus/static/plugins/spring-security-ui-1.0-RC1/css/smoothness/images/ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png"
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:8080/Proteus/static/plugins/spring-security-ui-1.0-RC1/css/smoothness/images/ui-bg_highlight-soft_75_cccccc_1x100.png"
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:8080/Proteus/static/plugins/spring-security-ui-1.0-RC1/images/safari-checkbox.png"
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:8080/Proteus/static/plugins/spring-security-ui-1.0-RC1/css/smoothness/images/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png"
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:8080/Proteus/static/plugins/spring-security-ui-1.0-RC1/css/smoothness/images/ui-bg_glass_75_e6e6e6_1x400.png"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out to be a setting in config.groovy. I had `grails.resources.processing.enabled = false` from a few months ago when I was having issues with the adding fonts. Hope this helps someone in the future!

```
environments {
development {
    grails.logging.jul.usebridge = true
    grails.resources.processing.enabled = false
}
production {
    grails.logging.jul.usebridge = false
    grails.resources.processing.enabled = false
    // TODO: grails.serverURL = "http://www.changeme.com"
}
```

}